# Stop leading whitespace being stripped with react-markdown

Tags: css, reactjs, react-markdown

Leading whitespace in my markdown file is being lost when rendering the text in a react-markdown component.

I am reading the file as follows,

```
fetch(file)
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((text) => this.setState({ markdown: text }));
```

and the render:

```
const { markdown } = this.state;
return (
  <Markdown
    className="textblock"
    children={markdown}
    remarkPlugins={[remarkBreaks]}
  >
)
```

If I have a line in the markdown file

`dog`

it is rendered as

`dog`

And if I have a line

`&nbsp;dog`

it is rendered the same,

`dog`

I have console log'd the 'text' variable from the first snippet (in the fetch), and can see that nbsp characters are preserved. So I think that I am using the react-markdown component wrong. It does not matter if I set the `textblock` property, `white-space: pre`, the whitespace has already been lost (does not exist in the react-markdown component's content).

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75159356/react-markdown-8-0-4-trims-white-spaces