# React-markdown 8.0.4 trims white spaces

Tags: html, css, reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

In previous version of react-markdown library I was using, 4.1.3 I could put space before and after some string and it was not trimmed. After upgrade to 8.0.4 there are trimmed. Is it possible to still have the previous behavior?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-tdd-ygrkdu

Now is rendered as `abc` and I would like to have `a b c`